# Active admin not finding partial in show

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin

This should be pretty simple, trying to render a partial on active admin in show action:

Object name is: Listing

```
ActiveAdmin.register Listing do
  show do
    attributes_table do
      row :foo
      row :bar
      render 'map'
     end
   end 
end
```

I added the partial under `app/admin/listings/_map.html.haml`

I get the no template found error:

```
Missing partial admin/listings/_map, active_admin/resource/_map, active_admin/base/_map, inherited_resources/base/_map, application/_map with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee, :arb, :haml, :jbuilder]}.
```

Also tried adding here: `app/admin/_map.html.haml` and `admin/listings/_map.html.haml`

And tried: moving the render outside the `attributes_table`, like so:

```
  show do          
    render 'map'
    attributes_table do
      row :foo
      row :bar
      ...
```

On `rails', '4.1.9'`, `'activeadmin', '~> 1.0.0.pre1'`

Comment: Have you tried **render partial: "map"**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your view should be put into `views` directory:

```
app/views/admin/listings/_map.html.haml
```

Rendering partial should look as follows:

```
show do
  render partial: 'map'
  # ...
end
```